# Change or completely remove the highlight color of an InfoWindow of the Google Maps v2 on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, highlight, google-maps-api-2, infowindow

Is there any possibility to change the highlight color of an InfoWindow in the Google Maps v2 component for Android? I already accepted the fact that there is no common way to apply custom press highlights for the widgets that reside in a custom InfoWindow View passed through a custom InfoWindowAdapter as the View is rerendered as Bitmap by the map control (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_windows see Note).
On the same website there is a hint at the very bottom (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_window_click_events) that says

> When a user clicks on an info window, onInfoWindowClick(Marker) will
>   be called and the info window will be highlighted in the default
>   highlight color (Holo Blue for devices running Ice Cream Sandwich and
>   newer, orange for earlier versions of Android).

So I tried to override the following theme values for my application

```
<item name="android:colorForeground">@color/black</item>
<item name="android:colorForegroundInverse">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:cacheColorHint">@color/white</item>

<item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:colorMultiSelectHighlight">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/white</item>
```

That should override all default highlight colors with white. Unfortunately it takes no effect at all :/

My assumption is now that the default highlight colors are hardcoded by Google Maps and thus don´t get retrieved from the values of the applied application theme. That means there would be no way to change the highlight color. I hope I´m wrong though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible yet, there is an acknowledged issue in gmaps-api-issues:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4783